# React intel and i18next React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-intl, react-i18next

I am building a multi language app with React-Native, I am little confuse about to choose the Internationalisation library and confusion is between two Libraries One is React-intel and other is React-i18next i talk about this with multiple developers and the answer was almost 50/50 that is why i am asking this question can anyone suggest me a good reason between both of the libraries that one is better,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at both the libraries, a few things I observed:

1. React-intel has 210 open issues, React-i18next has 0
2. They both have a similar weekly download figure (200-300 thousand)
3. The syntaxes are very different.

It's fair to say that since a large number of people are using each library, they will both work and will have a large network of users that could support you.

I think it's best that you look at each syntax and decide which one you like best because it will feature heavily in your code. Bear in mind that React-intel has a fair few open issues so may be more buggy...

Comment: then i think your suggestion is i18next, am i right?